# \newcommand: Combine (optional) star and optional parameter

Tags: macros

How may I define a new command that admits starred and non-starred variants, and that also admits an optional argument?

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyCommand[1][1]{%
  \@ifstar{%
    The starred variant with parameter: #1%
  }{%
    The non-starred variant with parameter: #1%
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\MyCommand    \\    
\MyCommand*   \\
\MyCommand[2] \\
\MyCommand*[2]
\end{document}
```

But this gives:

> The non-starred variant with parameter: 1
>   The starred variant with parameter: 1
>   The non-starred variant with parameter: 2
>   The starred variant with parameter: 1[2]

Yet, one can write `\MyCommand[2]*` to obtain "The starred variant with parameter: 2" but somehow I'd like the above version to work.

Comment: Please, avoid using the `minimal` class; it is not meant for minimal examples.

Comment: I learned many things with this question, including the fact that the `minimal` class is not made for minimal examples!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `xparse` it's very easy to play around with optional arguments and starred variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\MyCommand
  {
    s % optional *
    O{1} % first optional argument (default = 1)
  }
  {%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      {The starred variant with parameter: #2}
      {The non-starred variant with parameter: #2}
  }
\begin{document}
\noindent
\MyCommand   \\
\MyCommand*  \\
\MyCommand[2]\\
\MyCommand*[2]
\end{document}
```

With LaTeX's `\newcommand` it a little trickier. The `\@ifstar` macro looks at the next token after the macro is expanded and has absorbed its arguments, so you need to first check for the `*` and only then look for the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyCommand
  {%
    \@ifstar
      {\MyCommand@star}
      {\MyCommand@nostar}%
  }
\newcommand\MyCommand@star[1][1]{%
  The starred variant with parameter: #1%
}
\newcommand\MyCommand@nostar[1][1]{%
  The non-starred variant with parameter: #1%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent
\MyCommand   \\
\MyCommand*  \\
\MyCommand[2]\\
\MyCommand*[2]
\end{document}
```

Both versions print:

> [image]

Your code works, but not as you expect it to. The `\MyCommand[1][1]` looks for an optional argument “while expanding” `\MyCommand`, which then gives you:

```
\@ifstar{%
  The starred variant with parameter: <optional argument or default>%
}{%
  The non-starred variant with parameter: <optional argument or default>%
}
```

and only *after that* the `\@ifstar` test will be expanded to look for the optional `*` and choose the text accordingly, so the actual syntax for the command you defined is:

```
\MyCommand[optional argument]<optional star>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make `\MyCommand` take no parameters, but just figure out the star.  Then fork from there.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyCommand{%
  \@ifstar{\mycommandstar}{\mycommandnostar}
}
\newcommand\mycommandstar[1][1]{The starred variant with parameter: #1}
\newcommand\mycommandnostar[1][1]{The non-starred variant with parameter: #1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\MyCommand    \\    
\MyCommand*   \\
\MyCommand[2] \\
\MyCommand*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd add a `%` at the end of the definition of  `\MyCommand`. It works without that because the definition of `\@ifstar` ignores space tokens by design, but... :)